# Synology DSM Webapi access from Angular

Tags: angular, proxy, synology

After a successful login, every subsequent request returns error with code 105, but not form Postman.

I use Angular proxy to send my requests to the correct endpoint and the login does work, I get the token and everything, however when I use that token from Angular it gives me an error 105, if i use the same token from postman I get error 119. The weird thing is that if I log in from Postman, the token I get there works from postman, but still does not work from Angular trough the proxy.

Here is my proxy:

```
{
    "/webapi": {
        "target": "http://IP:PORT", //these are changed to the CORRECT values
        "secure": false
    }
}
```